# Boolean Values and Assertions

Tags: java, conditional-statements, assertion

I have the following method, which returns true if the first number is greater than the second number:

```
static boolean firstGreaterSecond(int x1, int x2) {
    boolean result;
    if (x1 > x2) {
        result = true;
    } else {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

I have added the following assertion:

```
    actual=MyClass.firstGreaterSecond(10,11);
    assert false==actual;
```

I was advised that it may be possible to replace false== with 1 character. I think they may be referring to ?, as in [explained here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/ControlFlow/cond-expr.html), but no matter how much I tried, I can't seem to get the right syntax. Could you please help?

Comment: Do you think i can use `Conditional Expression` there?

Comment: you can improve your code by returning : `return x1 > x2` instead of `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first off,

```
static boolean firstGreaterSecond(int x1, int x2) {
    boolean result;
    if (x1 > x2) {
        result = true;
    } else {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

can be rewritten as:

```
static boolean firstGreaterSecond(int x1, int x2) {
    return x1 > x2;
}
```

Secondly, you should be able to just:

```
actual=MyClass.firstGreaterSecond(10,11);
assert !actual;
```

Take a look at the [assert docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)

> The assertion statement has two forms. The first, simpler form is:
>
> `assert Expression1 ;`
>
> where Expression1 is a boolean expression. When
>   the system runs the assertion, it evaluates Expression1 and if it is
>   false throws an AssertionError with no detail message.

The negation of a `boolean` expression is also a boolean expression, hence `!actual` being valid for the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Both implementation and assertion can be simplified:

```
private static boolean firstGreaterSecond(int x1, int x2) {

       boolean result = x1 > x2;
        return result;
    }

actual=MyClass.firstGreaterSecond(10,11);
assert !actual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the alternative they are referring to is

```
assert(!actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean firstGreaterSecond(int x1, int x2) {
     return  (x1>x2)?true:false;
      }
```

What is wrong in this implementation??

**Assert will be like:**

```
actual=MyClass.firstGreaterSecond(10,11);
assert !actual;
```